# Understanding storage of OAuth token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have implemented ASP.NET Identity authentication and OAuth authorization according to this tutorial: `http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/`

It's currently working but i don't fully understand where the TOKEN and it's timer is stored.

This is the code that generates token:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
```

I would guess that token is stored in the ASP.NET Identity DB or within the hosted WEB API Application, but i don't fully understand.

Comment: The token is in memory of the application. It is not stored anywhere by default. You should look at IdentityServer implementation for a more robust oauth token provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the token is only generated once by the provider and it is not stored anywhere. It contains the information the application needs to authenticate the request and nothing more.

Assuming you use the Json Web Tokens or JWT, then the token is nothing more than a Json object with some properties, such as when it expires, the actual duration in seconds etc.

The token last for a configurable duration, so assuming you want to reuse that token for multiple calls then the client application will need to store somewhere in a safe manner. It could be in session for example, you could store the whole token and when you need it simply check if it's still active by looking at the duration. If it's not active anymore, you either refresh the current one you have or simply request another.

You could encapsulate all this nicely with something like this :

```
private TokenModel GetToken()
        {
            TokenModel result = null;

            if (this._systemState.HasValidToken(this._currentDateTime) )
            {
                result = this._systemState.RetrieveUserData().TokenData;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    result = this._portalApiWrapperBase.RequestAccessTokenData();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    this.LastErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    this._systemState.AddTokenData(result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

In my case all this user data is stored in Session and simply retrieved from there.

I am not showing all the code here, but I basically have a state provider where I store the token once I receive it the first time. The next time I need it, if it's still valid, I return it, or go and request another if it's not. All this is hidden from the app, you just call the GetToken method and it deals with everything else.

Now, the token is supposed to be application level, it's generated based on a ClientID and CLientSecret so you could easily request another one when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The token isn't stored. The user requesting the token needs to be able to pass the token on every request in order to make an authenticated call. So it's the responsibility of the client to store the token in order to do that. (that might be in-memory for short lived sessions or on disk/in a database for longer lived sessions.

There is no need for the server to store the token, since it is passed by the client on each request. One might store it in a db themselves on the server and check if the token is there. Using that kind of mechanism allows you to revoke a token by removing it from the db. There are other ways to do that though.

By timer I guess you mean the lifetime of the token. That is checked by the framework on every request. So there is no actual timer.